# Populate Google Play Music Searchbar with String passed from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having trouble **inserting a passed String from an intent into the google music app's searchbar.**
The following code allows me to open up Google Play Music from my app, but leaves the searchbar empty. **Would anyone know how to populate Google Play Music's searchbar with my passed in String? any help would be greatly appreciated.**

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.music");
intent.putExtra(song ,"song to be inserted in google play searchbar");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out thanks to the following [documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html#android-app)

In this example, i am opening up the google play store then entering `search?q=drake&c=music"));` as part of the URI to go to the music tab and search for drake

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/search?q=drake&c=music"));

                    startActivity(i);
```